# Find nested key in Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I'm getting the following node with nokogiri :

```
  <Instrument id="161" code="648">
    <Parameter key="currency" value="USD"/>
    <Parameter key="calendar" value="JAN"/>
  </Instrument>
```

which is a `Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet < Object`.

I want to get the value `"USD"`

I tried :
`node.search 'Parameter[key=currency]'` but I don't know how to retrieve the actual value.

So, how can I get the value "USD" ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you want since pointing to the node is easy:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<xml>
  <Instrument id="161" code="648">
    <Parameter key="currency" value="USD"/>
    <Parameter key="calendar" value="JAN"/>
  </Instrument>
</xml>
EOT

doc.at('Parameter')['value'] # => "USD"
doc.search('Parameter').first['value'] # => "USD"
```

`at` finds the first matching node, so `['value']` retrieves that node's `value` content.

`search` finds all matching nodes, and `first` retrieves the first node retrieved, which is what `at` does.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way :

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML::Document.parse <<-eot
<Instrument id="161" code="648">
    <Parameter key="currency" value="USD"/>
    <Parameter key="calendar" value="JAN"/>
  </Instrument>
  eot
doc.css('#161 Parameter').map{|e| e['value']}
# => ["USD", "JAN"]
# to get only 'USD' the below would work as per your example.
doc.at_css("#161 Parameter[key='currency']")['value']
# => "USD"
```

`doc.css` will give you [***`Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet`***](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html),where as `doc.at_css` will give you [***`Nokogiri::XML::Node`***](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html).`doc.css('#161 Parameter')` will give you all `Parameter` nodes,where as `doc.at_css("#161 Parameter[key='currency']")`,will give you first `Parameter` node.

> I tried : node.search 'Parameter[key=currency]' but I don't know how to retrieve the actual value.

You are very close. Just do

```
doc.search("Parameter[key='currency']").first['value']
# => "USD"
```